# Problema con select2: Etiqueta fantasma

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, bootstrap-4, select2

Estoy usando el siguiente select2 y bootstrap 4:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="card border-primary mb-3" >
                        <div class="card-header">Header</div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <select class="form-select" id="cmbSaldosContrarios">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Este es el código javascript que lo llena:

```
function llenarCombo(id,ruta,datos){
    $.ajax({
        url: ruta,
        type: "GET",
        data: datos
    }).done(function (respuesta, textStatus, jqXHR){
        cargaDatos=$.map(respuesta, function(obj){ 
            return { id: obj.data, text: obj.label} 
        });
        $("#"+id).find("option:gt(0)").remove();
        $("#"+id).select2({
            placeholder: "-Seleccione una opción-",
            data:cargaDatos
        });
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log("error\njqXHR=" + jqXHR + "\nstatus=" + textStatus + "\nerror=" + errorThrown);
        console.log(jqXHR );
    }).always(function (dataORjqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR_ORerrorThrown){
        //alert( "complete" );
    });
}
llenarCombo("cmbSaldosContrarios","${req.contextPath}/SaldosContrarios",[]);
```

El combo se llena perfectamente, pero el problema es que aparece una etiqueta al lado del combo con el texto que selecciono. Dicha etiqueta no quiero que aparezca ¿Como puedo quitarla?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: select2 necesita de su script y su css, te da eso por que algunos de ellos no se estan cargando correctamente

Comment: Gracias, me faltaba el CSS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

select2 necesita de su script y su css, te da eso por que algunos de ellos no se están cargando correctamente

Comment: mira debes agregar un ejemplo verificable a tu respuesta, que ratifique lo que dices; de lo contrario tu respuesta estará propensa a recibir votos negativos ... o incluso ser borrada puedes leer esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer y https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example